# How to allow submission to a list without acces to the list/site that contains it

Tags: list, infopath, site-collection, form

I have a list in a Site Collection ("IT Site Collection") with a Submission form built using InfoPath.  Only a few people have access to the "IT Site Collection" and I would like to keep it that way.  I am trying to find a way to give anyone the ability to submit to the list using the submission form that was built in InfoPath without giving everyone permission to the list and or the "IT Site Collection" which contains it.

Ideally, I would like to find a way to publish or at least have the InfoPath submission Form available on our Intranet Site colleciton which is different than the IT Site Collection.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple issue. 
1: Create 2 form libraries and publish the form as a site content type.
2: Add the form to both libraries
3: For library "A"  this is where the form is actually submitted, so make sure your submit button rules point to it.
4: workflow to move submitted form from Library "A' to Library "B" then delete original
5. Add form to a page with a web part
6. Allow users access to the page and library "A" only!